# Treatment of Markov process with absolute states

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

In the standard treatment of a markov process, the state vector is a probability vector, whose elements can be between zero and one. But I have a need to constrain the state vector to zeros or ones.  To be more precise, for my work, I need to constrain a state vector to be all zeros, and a single one, so that at every point in time the system is in a specific state.  I think this may be referred to as an "absolute state vector".

To give the system a history, with absolute state vectors, I must sample the transition matrix at each point in time in such a way that it consists of only zeros and ones.  If this is done properly, then the system moves from one absolute state to another.  So the system stays in a definite state at every time.

I know that it is possible to treat a markov process this way, but I can't find anywhere that somebody has done it.  I don't want to reinvent terminology or notation.  Can anyone please point me in the direction of where this treatment of a markov process has been established?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to observing a *sample path* of the Markov process?

Comment: Hello @Did.  Yes, it is.  My problem is that I can't find accepted notation for  writing out a sample path.  It isn't as simple as multipling the state vector by the transition matrix, because then you end up with a probability vector.  There is one paper where somebody makes a distinction between an "probablity state vector" and "an absolute state vector", which I think is useful terminology.  But this terminology is only found one paper.

Comment: Sorry but I am not convinced. What would this terminology be useful for?

Comment: RE: What would this terminology be useful for?  That is a valid question.  Unfortunately, the explanation is beyond what I can give in this limited space.  I can only say that for my particular subject, which started with a physics research question, I just don't see how I could proceed with out this "absolute vector" terminology.  But I could be wrong. In fact, if you would be willing to look at my paper and tell me if I'm using unnecessary notation, I'd probably be willing to send you a copy.

Comment: Let me rephrase: which aspects of what you re trying to do, does the name "sample path of the Markov process" leave out?

Comment: Hi,   The phrase "sample path of the Markov process" doesn't leave anything out.  But how do you actually write an equation that describes the dynamics or evolution of a sample path with each step in time?  I claim that you need to come up with some new definitions and notation to write down such an equation.